# Как получить количество определённых ключей ассоциативных массивов внутри массива?

Tags: php

У меня есть массив вида:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '532',
    'LASTNAME' => 'Henigan',
    'FIRSTNAME' => 'John',
    'BDAY' => 'Jan 24, 1998',
    'CLASS' => '[5] CL2',
    'CLASS_PRICE' => '200.00',
    'PID' => '530',
    'GCID' => '5',
    'AMOUNT' => '200.00',
    'billing_name' => 'BettyAnne Henigan',
    'parent_tuition' => '0.00',
    'DISCOUNT' => '0.00',
    'DISCOUNT_TYPE' => '0',
    'DISCOUNT_MODE' => '0',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '612',
    'LASTNAME' => 'Frantz',
    'FIRSTNAME' => 'Alan',
    'BDAY' => 'Mar 2, 1992',
    'CLASS' => '[4] CL1',
    'CLASS_PRICE' => '100.00',
    'PID' => '611',
    'GCID' => '4',
    'AMOUNT' => '100.00',
    'billing_name' => 'Bridget Frantz',
    'parent_tuition' => '0.00',
    'DISCOUNT' => '0.00',
    'DISCOUNT_TYPE' => '0',
    'DISCOUNT_MODE' => '0',
  ),
```

и так далее.

Как подсчитать количество значений 'PID' с одинаковыми значениями?

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант 1**

```
$arrayCounter = [];
//Посчитаем кол-во повторений
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $pid = $item['PID'];

    if (!isset($arrayCounter[$pid])) {
         $arrayCounter[$pid] = 1;
    } else {
         $arrayCounter[$pid]++;
    }
}
//Получим все, которые повторяются больше 1 раза
$result = array_filter($arrayCounter, function($var) {
      return $var>1;  
});

var_dump($result);
```

**Вариант 2**

```
$tempArray = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $tempArray[] = $item['PID'];
}

$result = array_filter(array_count_values($tempArray), function($var) {
      return $var>1;  
});

var_dump($result);
```

Выведет PID (ключ) и кол-во их повторений (значение), если нужно получить только ключи (PID), то нужно result прогнать через функцию array_keys;

Answer (score 0):

```
            foreach ($response['data'] as $item){
            $count[$item['ID']] += 1;
        }
```